# Access asks for entering a value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a form to search in person table.
But when I input text for searching and click to the 'Search' Button, it says Enter Parameter Value and so I input my text again and click OK, then it will work.
Here is the code that makes this problem(another_table created from lookup):

```
Task = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE (item1=(SELECT code_item2 FROM 
another_table WHERE name_item2=" & Me.txtSearch.Value & "))"
Me.RecordSource = Task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Me.txtSearch.Value is numeric

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE item1 ΙΝ (SELECT code_item2 FROM 
another_table WHERE name_item2=" & Me.txtSearch.Value  & ")"
```

if is alphanumeric then

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE item1 ΙΝ (SELECT code_item2 FROM 
    another_table WHERE name_item2='" & Me.txtSearch.Value  & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving a permanent SQL in form's recordsource, then simply call `.Requery` with search parameter change.  Doing so, you reference search text with absolute `Forms` reference and with `NZ`, you can set up a default value if search is empty like on form open. No concatenation or quote punctuation needed.

**SQL** *(save as stored query to be used in form recordsource)*

```sql
SELECT * FROM person 
WHERE item1 IN 
    (SELECT code_item2 FROM another_table 
     WHERE name_item2 = NZ(Form!myFormName!txtSearch, 'Default Value'))
```

**VBA**

```vb
Me.Form.Requery
```